# when user click on placed order, order pdf will generate and attached it to user's order email

Tags: magento2, orders, pdf, place-order

I want the following actions.

When any user clicks on "Place Order" on the checkout page,  A pdf of this order will be automatically generated. And this pdf is automatically attached to email "Your Main Website Store order confirmation" and send it with this email. So User can directly see or download order pdf from an email account.

I tried many free extensions But did not found a suitable free extension. I found that after a click on "Place Order" button, I have to generate pdf and send its link or attached pdf file in email. But I did not found a code of place order.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one, I used for one of my client. + Its free one.

> https://store.fooman.co.nz/magento-extension-email-attachments-m2.html

Comment: I allready installed it. But it is not display options as displayed on its screenshots.

Comment: do you see if module appears in app/etc/config.php ? Does it appears to be installed correctly ?

Comment: Yes. I am able to saw it in these manners : 'Fooman_PrintOrderPdf' => 1,

Comment: Are you trying this on vanilla Magento ? Try rm -rf generated/*; bin/magento setup:di:compile;

Comment: Yes I tried your commands. Still not getting option for send pdf as displayed in screenshot. Any other way?

Comment: Do you see Print Order option in Magento Backend when you open a particular order ?

Comment: Yes. There is a print option in backend when i open any order page.

Comment: 'Fooman_PrintOrderPdf' is different plugin which is needed to generate Order Pdf from Admin side. Does your config.php has 'Fooman_EmailAttachments' => 1 ?

Comment: No. I did not found this "Fooman_EmailAttachments". But I saw this "'Mageplaza_EmailAttachments' => 1,". This is for your information.

Comment: It means your extension was not correctly installed. Please go through the same link  i have provided in the answer. Download the plugin and the path should be like app/code/Fooman/EmailAttachment and remove Mageplaza_EmailAttachments if you installed it for trial purpose.Then do setup:upgrade.

Comment: Did it worked ??

Comment: I saw that admin side dropdown option is not display. I also not found xml code for admin side display. For this reason it is not working.

Comment: So is it working now ?

Comment: No.  Its not working.

Comment: Do you have placed new module at app/code/Fooman/EmailAttachment ??

Comment: I did not found folder "Fooman/EmailAttachment" in app/code folder path.

Comment: Can you please let me know which Magento version you are using ? is it 2.3 ??

Comment: Magento ver. 2.2.6

Comment: i found this extension in this path : magentowebsite/vendor/fooman/printorderpdf-implementation-m2. I found code here. Here Block,Controler, etc, i18n, Model, Plugin, view, registration.php, composer.json and readme file.

Comment: Then please download the file from this link https://file.io/fCJoqh . Extract the folder and copy the content of **src** folder into **app/code/Fooman/EmailAttachments** (create path if not exits). Now run bin/magento setup:upgrade

Comment: error 404 for above url.

Comment: check now https://file.io/fCJoqh

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/95046/discussion-on-answer-by-abdul-pathan-when-user-click-on-placed-order-order-pdf).